# How to use HTML classes and ID's

Tags: html, css, web

So I understand the difference between HTML classes & id's; however, I'm having a bit of a problem on how to use each in this particular situation.

I have about 25 div elements (5 columns, each with 5 inner divs). I want to use a consistent styling for each, so I used classes for the CSS. The problem comes now where I need to be able to identify each specific div because I'm using JQuery & Javascript, but I can't use both classes and id's because I would have to create a unique CSS style for each one, which defeats the purpose of using classes all together.

Here is the HTML code I'm working on:

```
<div class="ts8-10" id="dfwef">
<ul>
    <li>Jans Smith</li>
    <li><a href="#">Open Time</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I know this question may be a bit subjective, but I'm trying to figure out how I can maintain the advantage of using classes (being able to style multiple elements), while also being able to identify each element using id's.

When I added the ID to the class, all the styling provided by the class was lost. I know that I can use the CSS `.ts8-10#aa`, but then I would have to do that for each of the 25 elements.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here is the CSS if you need it:

```
    .ts8-10, .ts10-12, .ts12-2, .ts2-4, .ts4-6
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
    width:95%;
    height:15%;
    font-size: 28px; 
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top: 5px;    
}
```

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant. I'll post it. Hold on.

Comment: can you post your CSS with the HTML?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Classes are for styles, there is no need to have an id to make it styled a certain way. You can add ids all you want, there is no requirement to use an id in the CSS.

Comment: You can add a class only to format, maybe 'ts', and use `<div class="ts ts12-2" >` .

Comment: When you say you need to be able to identify each `div`, what do you mean? For what purpose and in what context are you looking to identify it?

Comment: Classes are not *just* for styles.

Comment: You have a huge pile of HTML and CSS here with only a vague description of what the problem is. It would help if you created a *reduced* test case which demonstrated the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can't use both classes and id's because I would have to create a unique CSS style for each one

Not so. You just write rule-sets which have class selectors that apply the common styles, and other rule-sets with id selectors that apply the unique styles.

There's no limit on the number of rule-sets that can be applied to a given element.

If two rule-sets match an element and provide values for the same properties, then the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) comes into play. This is such a fundamental part of CSS that it is mentioned in the language's name.

Comment: So then why is that when I added an ID to an element, all the styling was lost?

Comment: Adding an ID to an element will not cause any styling to be lost. It might cause specific rules to be overridden if it caused a rule-set with a more specific selector to be applied.

Comment: Okay, that's what I needed to know. Maybe there is something else going on then. I thought I could use ID's to identify and the class to style, but like I said, when I added the ID, all the styling was lost. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You were exactly right. When I started to dig into the code, I found that there was another element with the id that I was using (I'm using Wordpress, so apparently the id I selected had already been defined).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have classes and ids. Your CSS can use the class, and the Javascript can use the ids.

Or (less recommended), you could use the nth child selector in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Class = a style that you plan on using multiple times.

ID = a div that will be identified or used (depending on design preference when it comes to using ID for things that exist only once versus javascript functionality based on uniqueness) only once.

You can do things like `<input type="text" class="form_textbox" id="FORM_name" name="name">`

The logic:

- Use a class because the textboxes on this form all have the same styling
- Use an ID to identify it uniquely for JS/jQ form handling purposes

Make a bit more sense now..?

Answer (score 0):

ID's have greater specificity than Classes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

you could do a number of things.. for instance you can take this CSS rule:

```
.ts8-10, .ts10-12, .ts12-2, .ts2-4, .ts4-6
{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black; 
  width:95%;
  height:15%;
  font-size: 28px; 
  text-align: center;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top: 5px;    
}
```

and change it to this, since they are all the first children of .truck:

```
.truck > div
{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black; 
  width:95%;
  height:15%;
  font-size: 28px; 
  text-align: center;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top: 5px;    
}
```

the greater than (>) sign basically finds any first child of .truck

you can also try to just target tags since your basically repeating the same block of content over again in your columns

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what your actual problem is. That said, you don't need to have `#aa` in your CSS, just because you use it in your HTML. HTML doesn't require CSS at all.

Additionally, having `#aa { }` in your stylesheet will have no effect on the element with the `aa` id, because there are no styles declared in that rule. No styles declared does not mean everything is reset to nothingness. It just means that there's nothing overriding the previous declarations that apply to it.

You can use multiple classes on an element, if you want, to create a final look, or to otherwise group an element with others (for example, if you have "date" fields that you want the JavaScript to put a datepicker on, you can use the class to hit them all). You can also have an id and a class on the same element, and as long as you don't add CSS for that id, the id will have no effect on the look of the element.

Answer (score 0):

ID takes precedence over classes. Class don't have to be unique, ID's have to be unique.

Also if using Vanilla JavaScript it is used to easily select that element with the correseponding ID.

```
document.getElementById('idOfDiv');
```

If you had the follow HTML Mark Up

```
<div id="div1" class="divClass">
     <span>Cool Div</span>
   </div>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
 .divClass{
      color:#ff0000;
   }
 #div1{
      color:#000;
   }
```

Color of the text would be `#000` as id's take precedence like stated above.

To create a specific styling per each colomn create a stable class

```
.stable{
   width:200px;
   min-height:200px;
   height:auto;
   border-left:1px solid;
   border-right:1px solid;
 }
```

Then if we need to change certain criteria for other elements we can by doing so

```
.otherClassCol1{
  border-color:#ff0000;
  background:#fff;   
}
.otherClassCol2{
  border-color:#00ff00;
  background:#0000ff;   
}
```

Also you can change other critera for a select element with an id of `col4` per say

```
 #col4.stable{
     width:300px;
  }
```

Reason we add the specific `#col4.stable` is for purposes if the ID is on another page though doesn't have `.stable` in it our styles won't be overridden.
What that does is changes the stable class in col4 and makes the width bigger by `100px` there are so many ways to write a selector in CSS.

EXAMPLE http://jsfiddle.net/tw6uA/